# How do I align flexbox items to the baseline on a textarea input

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a very simple input form. I want to align the labels with the input controls so they are at the same level.

I've decided to use `align-items: baseline` because no matter what the padding, height, etc, it will always align correctly. But, for some reason, when using it with an input of type `textarea` it does NOT align to the baseline, it aligns at the bottom. Why?

Sure, I can fix it using `self-align` and `padding-top` for the `textarea`, but that defeats the purpose of having something flexible without the need of fixing the padding in some inputs.

I just need to understand to logic, or is this is a bug/known issue?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

form .control ~ .control {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.control {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.control>div:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 1 150px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.control>div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1;
}

.control input,
.control textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.control textarea {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="control">
    <div>
      <label>Label goes here</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="pretitle" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <div>
      <label>Article</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea name="article"></textarea>
      <p class="explain sub">HTML allowed</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <div>
      <label>Label</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="pretitle" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bnaL94u6/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the `textarea`  but the `padding` you are adding to both `input` and `textarea`, in textarea, you won't notice the it grows because `20px`x2 (`40px`) is not higher than `100px`, but the `input` itself without the `padding` has only `19px`, and when you add `40px` of `padding` it will have a total `height` of `59px`. and the the label will align in the middle of those `59px`

Comment: thanks, i guess it makes sense. i have no choice then to add a class to labels to align them correctly.